# Unable to expand node with toggleExpand() in FancyTree

Tags: jquery, fancytree

I have a lazy loading tree which all works fine, however I need to be able to expand a particular node in jQuery.  I've looked at the demo [here](http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/sample-source.html#) but I whenever I try to call `toggleExpand()` I get the following error (on IE9 which is the target platform on our intranet):

```
"0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'toggleExpand'"
```

My code is simply:

```
var node = $("#OrgDataTree").fancytree("getTree").getNodeByKey(key);
node.toggleExpand();

alert(node.key);  // testing for node, I see what I expect.
```

Using `node.expand()` gives the same result.  I've also tried grabbing the node from the `activate(event, data)` event as `data.node` but it also doesn't work for me (not that this is the case I need to use, I'm just trying to find *some* way of getting a handle to the node object that works).

It seems as though this should do what I need, according to any documentation I find, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you are using the old method names from Dynatree.
Fancytree uses 'toggleExpanded()' and 'setExpanded()' instead.
See also http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/doc/jsdoc/FancytreeNode.html

Comment: Thanks, this resolved my issue.  Given that the link in my question certainly state "FancyTree" not "DynaTree" it might be worth updating that document to reflect the new API?